# loops hashmap , insertion in hashmap through array

Tags: c++

```
int firstRepeated(int arr[], int n) {
        unordered_map<int,int>map;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            map[arr[i]]++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(map[arr[i]]>=2)
            {
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

can any one explain map[arr[i]]++. this line in detail.What we are doing here**

Comment: What does your favourite C++ book say about it?

Comment: And please don't add irrelevant tags. DSA is for digital signature algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
map[arr[i]]
```

retrieves a reference the value of the mapping with key `arr[i]`, if this mapping already exits. If the mapping doesn't exist yet, a new entry with a default initialized value is created and the value is returned.

`++` increments this value.

This means the first time a key `k` is encountered, the maping `k -> 0` is created and then the value is incremented changing the mapping to `k -> 1`.

For any subsequent call with the same key the mapping `k -> n` is changed to `k -> (n+1)`.